# How to save value with wildcard in Solr?

Tags: solr, wildcard

all. 
I have the following trouble with Solr. I need to implement "reverse" search with wildcards. I mean I want to keep value like "auto*" and this item should be found with request like "autocar", "autoplan" or "automate". Could someone help me with this, please? Thanks.

Comment: Could you please clarify what your expected input is vs. expected output? Is it correct assumption that within given history of queries: "autocar", "autoplan", "automate" you want to extract common prefix?

Comment: I want to save in solr text with wildcards. For example - if I kept text "gener*" in one Solr item - so I want to get this item for query "general", "generic" or "generock". IF I kept text " \*sav* " for item - I want to get it for query "save" or "autosave" (all this words are example).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match shorter indexed value (auto) against longer searched value (autobus), you want a custom analysis chain that includes [EdgeNGramFilter](http://www.solr-start.com/javadoc/solr-lucene/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ngram/EdgeNGramFilterFactory.html) on the **query side only**. Then, the incoming search word will get split into possible prefixes and matched against the indexed term.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I meant the ability to save in solr something like "template" with wildcards. For example - kepp the text "in\*v*". And if query contains text that matches this template - get this Solr item

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for Luwak then: https://github.com/flaxsearch/luwak